# How to setup internet through ethernet for a headless Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, headless

I have the following setup:
Ubuntu 18.04 PC connected with an ethernet cable to a raspberry pi 3+.

What I want: 
I am using ssh to connect to the Pi. I would like that the Pi can get internet access through the ethernet. Meaning, that the Pi is using the internet of the PC.

It would be nice if you could help me with a guide and tell me what I have to change in order to make it work.

What I tried:
I have a static IP on my PC as well as on the Pi.
In the network manager (nm-connection-editor), I set the IPv4 method to 'Shared to other computers'.
How do I now tell the Pi to use this network?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you can SSH into the Pi, it obviously is using the network connection already. You need to fix the routing on the PC side.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, not with ubuntu. And not with the information you have given (how is your PC connected to the internet, etc). You should easily find tutorials on how to set up ubuntu as router/firewall.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for raspberrypi.stackexchange.com